# Problems when trying to auto-generate the views for MVC3, from Controller's Action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When I try to create a view from action method of some controller (right click -> Add View -> select Strongly-typed view) I get the following error:

---

### The templates had the following 2 error(s) when running:

c:\Users(...)\AppData\Local\Temp\b1b5zy30.0.cs(5,33) : error CS0234: Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'DataAnnotations' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

c:\Users(...)\AppData\Local\Temp\b1b5zy30.0.cs(6,23) : error CS0234: Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

---

Does anyone knows what is going on?
This worked a couple of days ago, and meantime I didn't made any changes to MVC installation

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to apply the remedy suggested in the error messages i.e. add reference to System.ComponentModel and System.Data?

Comment: Check this One, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174420/why-cant-i-reference-system-componentmodel-dataannotations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got same error sometimes.

- Go to `c:\Users(...)\AppData\Local\Temp\` and delete *`.cs`* files in it.
- Close VS and stop any server (if running -in try icon you'll see the servers that are running), go to `%LocalAppData%\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files` (by typing it Windows-Explorer's address-bar and Enter) and delete all file and folders there.
- Go to `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v(YOUR-VERSION)\Temporary ASP.NET Files` and delete all files and folders there.
- Clean and ReBuild entire solution.
- Run it!

This steps should resolve the problem. Check it out.

Comment: this method didn't work for me, however uninstalling t4 as recommended by @emilast worked.

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur after installing tangible T4 editor (http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html). Uninstalling it fixed the problem for me.

/Emil