# Why can't I reference System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-annotations

I'm trying to use DataAnnotations in my WPF project to specify a maximum length of strings, with the following:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

However, I get the error

> The type or namespace name 'DataAnnotations' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

I've seen other examples where `DataAnnotations` *does* exist in this namespace. I'm using C#4. Is there any reason why I can't use this? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Have you got MVC installed? I believe DataAnnotations belongs to that package

Comment: Perhaps you are "missing an assembly reference."

Comment: Error messages are designed to be helpful, not to be ignored.

Comment: Ok guys, forgive me for appearing ignorant, but I am referencing the assembly `System.ComponentModel` and using various other components in that. According to @Hari below, it appears that `DataAnnotations` exists in its own assembly. I thought it would exist within `System.ComponentModel` as it's in the same namespace.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You have to reference the assembly in which this namespace is defined (it is not referenced by default in the visual studio templates). Open your reference manager and add a reference to the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations assembly (Solution explorer -> Add reference -> Select .Net tab -> select System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations from the list)

Comment: What is odd here is that VS was not able to give me the normal 'Potential Fix' for this one.  Wonder why...

Comment: In VS2019, the .net tab is not there (anymore). 
Check JohnB's more recent answer which is working for me !

Comment: In VS 2017 I find it by right clicking the project > add > reference > Assemblies tab > System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations checkbox

Comment: I had no explicit reference in my project, but it worked. It did not work on another developer's PC though, I had to explicitly add the reference in the project. Why is that???

Answer (score 49):

If using **.NET Core** or **.NET Standard**

use:

> Manage NuGet Packages..

[image: Use Manage NuGet Packages]

instead of:

> Add Reference...

[image: Don't use Add Reference]

Comment: From the command line `dotnet add package System.ComponentModel.Annotations`

Comment: also via installing nuget package manager in VSCode, - - > followed by the command "command+shift+p" (on mac) - - > and typing in "Nuget Package manager" and selecting "add package" from the autocompleted list - - > and typing in System.. and waiting for autocomplete to show the correct package and selecting "System.ComponentModel.Annotations" - - > and selecting the project where this assembly needs to be included - - > and selecting "restore" if needed to establish the reference.

Answer (score 12):

**To Reference System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations**

In a code file to have Using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; at the top of the file such as:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Add a .NET reference to your project by right clicking the project in solution explorer:

[image]

Hope this helps! This question helped me.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have it in references (like I did not) you can also add the NuGet System.ComponentModel.Annotations to get the assemblies and resolve the errors. (Adding it here as this answer still top of Google for the error)

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem and I resolved by adding the reference in one of my projects which didn't had the mentioned reference. If you have 2-3 projects in your solution, then check by adding this reference to the other projects.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I cannot reference System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations from Silverlight 5 with the below version at (1).  I found that Silverlight 5 assemblies cannot use .NET assemblies, it gives the error "You can't add a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations as it was not built against the Silverlight runtime. ..."  I plan to workaround this by hopefully installing the Silverlight 5 package found at (2) below.  If this fails I will update this post.

[UPDATE:  it failed.  I installed everything relating to Silverlight 5 and I don't have the Silverlight version of the .dll assembly System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations .  Too bad. UPDATE II:  I found an old .dll having this name from a previous installation of Silverlight developer's kit for Visual Studio 2008 or 2010. I added this file and it seems to 'work', in that IntelliSense is now recognizing attributes on class members, such as  `[Display(Name = "My Property Name")].`  Whether or not this works for everything else in this .dll I don't know.]

(1)

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.21005.1 REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51641
```

Installed Version: Professional

(2)
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229318

Comment: Update III - I could not get System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll to work on the client side, for Silverlight 5, but strangely on the server side the Silverlight project uses the .NET v4.5.1 version of this .dll just fine.  But the client side will not accept the .NET version, and demands a Silverlight version of this .dll, which as of this date I cannot find anywhere.  So you must do without on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

I searched for help on this topic as I came across the same issue.

Although the following may not be the Answer to the question asked originally in 2012 it may be a solution for those who come across this thread.

**A way** to solve this is to check where your project is within the solution. It turns out for my instance (I was trying to install a NuGet package but it wouldn't and the listed error came up) that my project file was not included within the solution directory although showing in the solution explorer. I deleted the project from the directory out of scope and re-added the project but this time within the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

Use the FrameWork version 4.5 and above for your project then problem solved.Because this namespace is under 4.5 and above.

Comment: that's incorrect. see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5.x and it is not included.  But, then I am not using MVC. This app is a console app with no UI that will be run as a cron job once a day. I only want to use DataAnnotations in the classes that represent the data members that will hold the data from columns I retrieve from each SQL Server table row. I'll try adding it manually as a reference.

Comment: Have a look on it ;[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx#Interfaces)

Comment: @user2090762: the namespace exists, but not all of the classes yet exist.  In particular the EmailAddressAttribute is not available until 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations is contained in its own assembly so you need to make sure you have it refernced. Just simply:

1). Right click on Soloution and choose add.

2). Choose reference from the list.

3). Search " System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation " and tick the check box on its left hand side and press ok.

Job done, shouldnt have any refernce errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to update visual studio from vs2008 to vs2010. And your app uses framework 3.5 (and you don't want to upgrade it), and also used WCF RIA Services BETA... I have bad news... you MUST upgrade to WCF RIA Services v1 (BETA does not work on vs2010)... and due to this... you also have to install Silverlight 4 + upgrade to framework 4.0

See this:
http://blog.nappisite.com/2010/05/updating-visual-studio-2008net-35-ria.html

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from Silverlight 4 to Silverlight 5 and then I was having this issue.  Although I had a reference to "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" under "References" in my project, it had a yellow yield sign by it that indicated the previously referenced assembly could not be found.  It turned out that the properties of the "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" reference indicated "Specific Version = True", when I changed this to "Specific Version = False" it fixed the issue.  Right click on the "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" assembly under "References" and select "Properties" from the context menu.  Check that the property value for "Specific Version = False".

It must have been referencing the old Silverlight 4 assembly which was no longer available after the upgrade to Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem.
That is very stupid when i add a namespace the same with System. I try to remove all references, but it is not resolved. I use "global::System.ComponentModel", it is working as well.
When i remove my namespace, this problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For .Net Core in Visual Studio 2019 try this.
[see VS suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPZDE.png)

It worked for me, hope it'll work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was moving from .Net Framework 4.7.2 to .Net Standard 2.0.

In my case, I had to change `DataAnnotations`'s reference from an Assembly reference to a Nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

if you meet this problem again in Visual 2022, you can try this fix (it worked for me):

You just add:

```
using RequiredAttribute = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute;
```

I hope it'll work for you as well. Good luck =)))))

Answer (score -1):

```
This error occurs when the reference to the "System.dll" got removed.Solution to the problem is very simple add the reference to "System.dll".The dll is normally available in the following location
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727" .Add the reference your problem will get solved .
```

Answer (score -1):

There was a problem using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation in net40 so I just did:

```
#if !NET40
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
#endif

#if !NET40
        [StringLength(256)]
#endif
```

The NET40 must be a predefined macro definition for .Net Framework 4.0

Answer (score -7):

I had same problem, I solved this problem by following way.

Right click on page, select Property. in build action select Content.

Hope that this solution may help you.

Comment: Which "page" are you referring to? And how does that helps exactly?

Comment: Well, this is really wrong. If you make a project element be treated as "Content" during build, it will lose its behavior. So if you do it on a class, it will no longer be compiled and it's code won't be called ever. Instead it will be copied as a file along the binaries of the program compilation output. That is why you will stop receiving compilation errors, but it is definitely not a solution to a compilation problem.