# 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' already installed. Failed to add reference to 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My winforms solution was working, but when I re-opened it, some of the references were no longer working.  Hence I removed all the references in the project including the references to microsoft dlls.

Now I am trying to add back the references.
What should I do first?

I tried using package manager to add Entity Framework, but got an error.
 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' already installed. Failed to add reference to 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations'.

Now When I open package manager, and select On Line, Entity Framework is ticked.  However when I select Installed Packages it states "No packages are installed in the current solution"

When I try to build I get an error message

```
Error   1   This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is E:\EShared\devnet10\SBD.Scheduling\\.nuget\NuGet.targets.  E:\EShared\devnet10\SBD.Scheduling\SBD.Scheduling.Core\SBD.Scheduling.Core.csproj   117 5   SBD.Scheduling.Core
```

I tried adding a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations but it shows in the references with a little yellow exclamation mark.

When I double click the reference icon in solution exporer I get the message

```
The project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built
```

After using version control to revert back to my version with EF6.0.2 , I was then able to install 6.0.3 successfully.

I would still like to know what went wrong.

Comment: did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10174457/1845408

Comment: Pro Tip: If you _installed_ it with nuget, you need to _uninstall_ it with nuget. Manually editing the references node of your project leaves the packages/projects out of sync. Probably going to need to manually remove reference from `packages.config`.

Comment: yes, i  removed from packages.config and deleted the EF folder within the packages.

Comment: it seems i cant add any reference.  I am looking into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909506/this-project-references-nuget-packages-that-are-missing-on-this-computer

Comment: Did you make sure you have the latest version of the Nuget extension on your VS?

Answer (score 4):

1. Close your Visual studio.
2. From the Start screen, right-click the Windows PowerShell app tile (or search for it in the search bar).
3. Click `Run as administrator` (Very Important).
4. Run this command:
   `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
5. Now go back to your visual studio and download your Nuget package(s).
6. Run this command to set it back to secure setting:
   `Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted`

Comment: Thanks, I will try this next time I have the problem. I cant remember what I did to work around it at the time.... but Run as administrator sounds familiar and Set-ExecutionPolicy sounds new.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this command from the Package Manager Console:

**Update-Package –reinstall EntityFramework**

If you just want to reinstall everything that is defined in packages.config, use this command:

```
nuget install packages.config
```

It will also restore the missing packages.

Comment: sadly this did not help.