# How to display 2 or 3 numbers after the decimal separator in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, decimal

I have `Article` model which has property `SellPrice`. I want wherever I use it to be displayed with `2` numbers after the decimal separator. It always has value of `2` numbers after the decimal separator but when the `price` is for example `2,30` it's displayed as `2,3` and I want to be displayed as `2,30`. The same thing happens for property `Quantity` in the same `Article` model I want it to be displayed with 3 numbers after the decimal separator for example if its value is `1,1` to be displayed as `1,100`. For `SellPrice` I tried the following:

```
[Column("sell_price")]
[XmlElement(ElementName = "sell_price", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
public decimal SellPrice { get; set; }
```

But `DisplayFormat` is underlined with red and I'm not allowed to import its namespace using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. I guess it's deprecated. For displaying `3` numbers after decimal separator I didn't find even something deprecated. I found a lot of ways to do it using `String.Format` but I use `SellPrice` and `Quantity` in a lot of places in my project and I don't want every time when I use the model properties to write `String.Format`...... Is there any way to specify that in the model as attribute for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
public string QuantityDisplay
{
    get
    {
        return String.Format("{0:0.000}", Quantity);
    }
}
[Column("sell_price")]
[XmlElement(ElementName = "sell_price", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd")]
//[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")]
public decimal SellPrice { get; set; }
public string SellPriceDisplay
{
    get
    {
        return String.Format("{0:0.00}", SellPrice);
    }
}
```

Wherever I want to make calculations I use `Quantity` and `SellPrice` properties. Wherever I want to display `Quantity` and `SellPrice` I use `QuantityDisplay` and `SellPriceDisplay` properties.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use a private field to save the value in and have two properties `SellPrice` and `SellPriceString` as followed, this way you can re-use the `SellPriceString` property instead of formatting the string each time you want to use the `SellPrice` property:

```
decimal _sellPrice;
public decimal SellPrice
{
    get
    {
        return _sellPrice;
    }
    set
    {
        _sellPrice = value;
    }
}

public string SellPriceString
{
    get
    {
        return _sellPrice.ToString("N2");
    }
}
```

Using a [Standard Numeric Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) as parameter in your `ToString` method. You would do exactly the same with your `Quantity` property, but using the Standard Numeric Format "N3", once again refer to the link for more information on the format.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it using `[DisplayFormat]` attribute as in MVC?

Comment: @Profile3ForStack Were you able to import the namespace already? If not, you might want to have a look at this topic on SO, more specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10174457/7016022. I do not work with MVC while developing a Xamarin.Android app, I use MVVMCross.

Comment: @Profile3ForStack If this solved your problem, please accept my answer. If not, can you give us an update?

Comment: "C2" makes currency to display too. I don't want that. I pass bellow my solution which has part of the suggestions in that post and part of my way to do it. I think it responds the best way to the question. I gave you +1 because part of your solution lead me to my solution.

Comment: @Profile3ForStack You could just use "N2" then.. That's why I referred to this documention: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings, I don't see any reason why you wouldn't accept my answer. I edited my answer to reflect what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

> How to display 2 or 3 numbers after the decimal separator in Xamarin.Android?

You could try using `SellPrice.ToString("C2")`,  refer to: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).

For example:

```
SellPrice = 12.545646M;
Debug.WriteLine("SellPrice.ToString(C2) == " + SellPrice.ToString("C2"));

[0:] SellPrice.ToString(C2) == ￥12.55
```

Comment: But I want to set it in one place(in the model for example) and then wherever I use it to be displayed always with 2 numbers after the decimal separator even when the number is 7,6 for example , not everytime I have to use SellPrice to have to put some formating code.

Comment: Then create a model property 'string SellPriceDisplay' and include the above code in the 'get' part.